# deploy solution to cdn with source maps

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I have a webpart that works fine in the workbench but when I deploy it to the appcatalog and my cdn, it is not behaving the same as it does on the workbench.(I am rendering a fabric CommandBar that has nested IContextualMenuItem's-- in the Workbench I can select one of the nested items and its onClick fires, when deployed to cdn  when I click on the parent IContextualMenuItem yo get to the nested menu item the page refreshes. This could be an bigger issue if webparts in general behave differently when deployed than how they do on the workbench... but I digress).

When I start to debug it in chrome, all I see is the transpiled javascript code.

Is there any way to deploy to the cdn along with the sourcemaps so I can see the typescript code when I am debugging?
Russell

UPDATE:
Now I don't even see the transpiled code: When I open the file in the chrome debugger (from the sources tab) all I see is

(function(System, SystemJS, require) {
})(System, System);

I deployed to the cdn with debugger statement in the code, but they have been stripped away by the tooling, so I see no way to diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Known issue - workaround here - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/328 .  A fix should be rolled out in a bit.

Comment: Thanks Pat. This fix did not work for me. I am having this issue after packaging and deploying the solution-- not in the workbench,

Comment: Also, and more importantly I think, I need to beable to have an option deploy the source maps when I bundle the solution.   And also and option to leave any debugger statements in ther if needed to trobleshoot issues that arise whenn thinks work in the workbench, but not when deployed.

Comment: Yes - right, sorry.  The same fix will roll to the service as well.  We had to back the last one out just before it went live because the version of system.js that contains the fix had other errors.

Comment: ok, thanks. what about bundling source maps and dbuuger statements for seployment , is that doable. now, or on the radar?